# java program to check periodically ms outlook for new mail

Tags: java, web-services, event-listener

I need the solution for the below problem in Java -

On arrival of new mail in ms outlook for a particular email id, there should be a web service get executed automatically.

is it possible? please help!

Comment: Forget the outlook, just like(config) as outlook get connected to the server, do the same for the java app. and dependents to the protocol IMAP or POP3 you need to check it with interval, or just waits for server push messages. another possible way is listening on the outlook out port that this would be a native thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using java mail. You will need to find the configuration details but a standard code snippet for this would be something like [below](http://metoojava.wordpress.com/tag/store-in-java/). I copied the code snipped from here. Thos official [javamail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/javamail-138606.html) link has a pretty decent set of examples (ie. how to read attachments).

For storing the email as a file to a folder, you can apache FileUtils. Write the email to a file and copy it to a folder that you desire.

There is one more interesting [resource](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/62143-how-to-read-your-emails-using-java/)