# java read MS Outlook inbox

Tags: java, outlook

I would like to use java (SE) to read my Inbox in MS Outlook (2010) and then move message/email to another folder. I have tried to search on web, but found only licensed solutions or posts old couple of years. Does anyone have solution for this step? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Possible Duplicatte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623068/java-program-to-check-periodically-ms-outlook-for-new-mail

Comment: Do you need to automate Outlook or just access emails?

Comment: Hello Eugene, I need to automate outlook itself, not to access emails...unfortunately. Do you know if there is solution for this situation? Thank you very much for your willingness to help me!

Comment: Try the solution mentioned, let me know if it serves your purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can be done using javax.mail, but a lot depends on the protocol of the server and authentication etc.

Anyways, here is a snippet (assuming imap):

Set your properties:

```
Properties props = new Properties();        
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.user", <user>);
props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", <host>);
props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", <port 143>);
...
```

Get a session and connect

```
Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);   
Store mailStore = mailSession.getStore("imap");
mailStore.connect(<host>, <user>, <passwd>);                    
Folder dFolder = mailStore.getDefaultFolder();
Folder inbox = dFolder.getFolder(<connectFolder=INBOX?>);
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

 // Open destination folder, create if reqd
Folder destfolder = mailStore.getFolder(<destination folder>);
if (!destfolder.exists())
   destfolder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);

Message []inMessages = inbox.getMessages();
if (inMessages .length != 0) {
    inbox.copyMessages(inMessages , destfolder);

    for (int i=0; i< inMessages.length; i++) { 
      // Custom Processor which readsMessages and performs some action.
      // getProcessor().readMessage(inMessages[i]);
       inMessages[i].setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Kedar, thanx for guiding me. However, I need to physically move mails within MS Outlook application itself and if I get this correctly, its opening and reading the mails not through Outlook itself, right? I have to say that I am newbie to Java as well as on this forum, thus I am very sorry if my assumption is not correct.

Comment: Hi Cavax, I have made changes, Thus the java prog will connect to your inbox read the messages, copy to a folder and then remove them from Inbox.

Comment: I have tested the code and I am struggling with two problems.  Folder destfolder = store.getFolder("Inbox"); IDE says cant resolve symbol 'store' and line  getProcessor().readMessage(inMessages[i]); getprocessor() - cant resolve method 'getProcessor'. I use IntelliJ not sure if it helps. Do you have any idea what can cause it?

Comment: The connectFolder would the mostly INBOX or the folder in which you expect your mail.